# Means for performing background operations in Scala

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency

I'd like to do some time consuming task in background. So I need to start computation in a different thread, be able to check if it is completed (maybe failed) and be able to abort the computation when it becomes unnecessary. After computation is ended it should call synchronized callback function to store computed value.

It may be programmed as some wrapper over the Thread class. But I suppose that this basic functionality is implemented in some scala library already. I've tried to search but find only Akka that is too much for my simple task. `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext` has useful `execute` method but it return no object to check status of the computation and abort it on demand.

What library contains already described functionality?

---

I've checked `scala.concurrent.Future`. It lacks ability to abort computation, that is crucial. I use following strategy: compute some consuming function in background and provide reasonable default. If arguments to the function is changed, I drop the original computation and start new. I could not imagine how to rewrite this strategy in terms of Future.flatMap.

Comment: You should take a look at futures—they're designed to provide the kind of facilities you're describing, although in idiomatic use you don't "check the status" of the computation—you use `Future`'s monadic combinators to compose computations. [Twitter's implementation](https://github.com/twitter/util) provides interruption off the shelf, and I believe it's not too hard to do something similar with the standard library futures.

Comment: I've considered `Future`s already. `scala.concurent.Future` is a trait - it could not be instantiated and I could not find any concrete realization of it. There are also `Future`s in akka and in scalaz. I suppose that is common name used in many frameworks and libraries and that make googling harder. And I have no need to compose computation. I'm working on application that have little use of concurrency, so cumbersome frameworks like akka are discouraged

Comment: You don't instantiate `Future` by hand—you use `Future.apply` on the companion object (or `Promise.apply` in some special cases).

Comment: Note that there is no general reliable way to abort computations using thread-based APIs in Java or Scala - your computation either has to support aborting itself (e.g. by checking a flag periodically) or you need to use a process-based API (e.g. [scala.sys.Process](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.sys.process.package)) since processes can be terminated when desired.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29 Documentation says that `Future.cancel(true)` could interrupt the thread executing the task

Answer (score 2):

I'll give a demonstration of how use futures with [Twitter's implementation](https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/index.html#com.twitter.util.Future), since you asked for cancellation:

```
import com.twitter.util.{ Await, Future, FuturePool }

def computeFast(i: Int) = { Thread.sleep(1000); i + 1 }
def computeSlow(i: Int) = { Thread.sleep(1000000); i + 1 }

val fastComputation = FuturePool.unboundedPool(computeFast(1))
val slowComputation = FuturePool.unboundedPool(computeSlow(1))
```

Now you can poll for a result:

```
scala> fastComputation.poll
res0: Option[com.twitter.util.Try[Int]] = Some(Return(2))

scala> slowComputation.poll
res1: Option[com.twitter.util.Try[Int]] = None
```

Or set callbacks:

```
fastComputation.onSuccess(println)
slowComputation.onFailure(println)
```

Most of the time it's better to use `map` and `flatMap` to describe how to compose computations, though.

Cancellation is a little more complicated (this is just a demo—you'll want to provide your own cancellation logic):

```
import com.twitter.util.Promise

def cancellableComputation(i: Int): Future[Int] = {
  val p = Promise[Int]

  p.setInterruptHandler {
    case t =>
      println("Cancelling the computation")
      p.setException(t)
  }

  FuturePool.unboundedPool(computeSlow(i)).onSuccess(p.setValue)
  p
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val myFuture = cancellableComputation(10)
myFuture: com.twitter.util.Future[Int] = Promise@129588027(state=Interruptible(List(),<function1>))

scala> myFuture.poll
res4: Option[com.twitter.util.Try[Int]] = None

scala> myFuture.raise(new Exception("Stop this thing"))
Cancelling the computation

scala> myFuture.poll
res6: Option[com.twitter.util.Try[Int]] = Some(Throw(java.lang.Exception: Stop this thing))
```

You could probably do something similar with the standard library's futures.

Comment: I've googled already that the single way to stop a computation is to call deprecated Thread.stop(). All other means require to write computation in a special form. That checks for thread's interrupted value.

Comment: @ayvango What Twitter's futures' interruptibility allows you to do is build up a computation graph that interruptions will be propagated through. If you wrote `myFuture.map(_ + 1)`, for example, you'd get a new future, and if you interrupted that new future, `myFuture` would be interrupted as well.

Comment: I ended with writing small utility that provides fixed worker pool and utilise Thread.stop() to kill threads safely in the middle of computation